# How to get JSON file from Minio nodejs

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb, buffer, minio

I need to get a json file from minio and insert to mongoDB by mongoose

I'm getting Buffer with getObject method

here is my code

```
let miniData
        minioClient.getObject(fileData.type,fileData.userId+fileData.fileName,function(err,exData) {
            exData.on('data',function (chunck) {
                miniData=JSON.stringify(chunck)
            })
            return miniData       
        })
```

I take the codes from Minio's documentation.The data coming as numbers and Buffer but my file is json.I couldn't handle it.

Answer (score 2):

Since it is stream of data you need to keep on appending it and then use it when it is finished. something like this should work

```
let miniData
        minioClient.getObject(fileData.type,fileData.userId+fileData.fileName,function(err,exData) {
            exData.on('data',function (chunck) {
                miniData += chunk;
            });
exData.on('end',function (chunck) {
                const response = JSON.stringify(miniData);
            });
        })
```

Comment: Without stringify its done.Thanks but interestingly i cannot insert into mongoDB in callback or outside of callback